# iOS - Connecting BLE device to app and iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-bluetooth

Is it possible for a BLE device to be connected to an iOS device using Bluetooth classic (via settings) and also be connected to the same device using BLE via an application?

Comment: Do you have an example? What have you tried? Theoretically there is no restriction that would prevent this from happening. The Two interfaces are independent of each other from the perspective of the iOS device.

Comment: For example can a Bluetooth 4.0 headset be connected to an app via coreBluetooth and also be connected to iOS for calls and music (e.g using HFP or A2DP)?

Comment: Also why are there Bluetooth 4.0 headset when such devices are not BLE devices; how is a Bleutooth 4.0 headset better?

Comment: Bluetooth 4.0 includes the previous Bluetooth profiles, including Handsfree, but 4.0 doesn't add anything to this profile - so I suspect that some manufacturers are using the latest generation of Bluetooth chips that include BT 4.0 and using it in their marketing material even though they aren't doing anything specific with BT 4.0.  In theory a BT4.0 headset could include additional functionality, such as fitness monitoring, heart rate monitoring etc that does use BT 4.0

Comment: BLE is low throughput. It's barely enough to transmit sound. Apple's engineers have been talking about this in the WWDC videos. There are hearing aids that use BLE but it took sweat and blood to squeeze sound into the available bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can for example use A2DP music streaming by connecting via the Settings menu and establish a concurrent BLE link from your app. Some versions of BT chips have restrictions, though, that prevent you from being a BT Classic Slave and a LE Peripheral at the same time. For these chips, BT Classic Slave + LE Central should work fine. From the iPhone side, it's no problem.

Comment: So a Bluetooth 4.0 device with dual mode can maintain simultaneous connections with a classic device and a BLE application? But what I don't understand is the benefit of a Bluetooth 4.0 headset since it cannot make use of energy savings; unless it is connected to the phone via BLE when not actively used and classic Bluetooth when a call is live (i.e. when more bandwidth is needed)

Comment: BT 4.0 did also introduce other benefits than BLE, afaik.